# Delivering video across all browsers

Tags: video

I have a source video. In order to play it in all major browsers (IE7+, Chrome, Safari, Firefox), how many formats do I need to convert the video to? Will using a single .mp4 file be sufficient? What exactly is the `webm` format, and is it required that I additionally convert my video to this?

In addition, what are some open source video players that would be able to play this format(s) in all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flowplayer is the opensource player which is easy to integerate in your website. It can play formats like flv and mp4 in all browsers.

here is a link to it:

http://flowplayer.org/

Another opensource player is JW Player. you can find it here:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of supporting the html5 video tag, I believe firefox and opera only support ogg/vorbis and I don't see them getting .mp4 support in the very near future (.3gp and .mp4 are patented). You will need to fall back to a plugin like flash or silverlight, as I imagine the above players do for xcc.

Comment: So, in other words, if I'm using a flash player, I can use an mp4 file and it will work in all browsers?