# convert any video format to .flv format using php script

Tags: php, jquery

I have a question regarding video conversion during uploading to .flv format. Is it the best solution to convert video of any format to .flv format so that video can be in all browsers easily as there are issues with different codecs in different browsers. Please guide which is the best solution to play every video on all browsers.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you taken a look at http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Video-Conversion-With-FFMPEG.html#2

Comment: yes i know that ffmpeg is used to convert videos but i am asking is this a good solution or not?

Comment: Look at this to see what format(s) you should use http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html

Comment: The best videoformat for web is WebM. FLV is flash and bad.

Comment: *"...to play every video on all browsers."* - It will depend whether or not the user installed the right plug-in for it; i.e. Quicktime etc. The most widely used is Flash which is what YouTube uses, as I'm sure you know that already ;)

Comment: thanks. i know which browsers support which codecs i have already search a lot on this topic but i want to take some advices to on the solution i have asked in my question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Using WebM and HTML5 Player would result in no plugins needed. Only a good and updated browser like Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: @user3456241 FFmpeg is basically **the** solution.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois You would be surprised as to how many are still using outdated browsers.

Comment: Note that FLV won't run on most tablets/phones.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's no reason or excuse to use old formats. If they're not updating, that's their problem. That's why my websites do look strange on outdated browser. But that's none of my business.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois The Web's come a long way since IE 2.0 ;) *ah*, the good 'ol days.

Comment: WebM is a good solution for most browsers, however it isn't supported by Safari, iOS, nor is it supported by IE users without VP8 codec. You should do multiple encodings. One with WebM and another with H.264, AAC or MP4

Comment: Also note that Google Chrome promised it would drop H.264 in 2011 (it hasn't yet from what I'm aware)

Comment: I think .flv is the best solution without any compatibility issues.

Comment: Check out these pages http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/use-html-5-video-on-all-browsers/ and http://stackoverflow.com/a/7186195/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats - I suggest you first sniff out what OS/browser they're using, then use a conditional statement to redirect and/or load accordingly/respectively. That way, you should be able to cover all the bases, *as it were*. ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delivering video across all browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7186174/delivering-video-across-all-browsers)

Answer (score 2):

> For maximum compatibility, here’s what your video workflow will look like:
>
> 1. Make one version that uses WebM (VP8 + Vorbis).
> 2. Make another version that uses H.264 baseline video and AAC “low
>      complexity” audio in an MP4 container.
> 3. Make another version that uses Theora video and Vorbis audio in an Ogg container.*
> 4. Link to all three video files from a single `<video>` element, and fall back to a Flash-based video player.
>
> * WebM and H.264 have sufficient support. So, unless you're supporting Firefox 3.5 or Opera 10.5, you can drop Theora.

From http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html

This link explains everything you could possibly want to know about video in HTML and more.
The author of the website deserves an *A+*

Comment: The author does indeed. Kinda of what I said in a [`later comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429719/convert-any-video-format-to-flv-format-using-php-script#comment39672877_25429719) as an "in a nutshell" kinda thang ;) but this explains it well.